# Get localized string on the fly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-localization

I am trying to run a seeder for getting a string in different locale (I stored the lang file in `lang/es.json`).

(For being able to search in both english and spanish, I needed to store both values in database). Now, I'm trying to run it inside my seeder:

```
 App::setLocale('es');
 dd(__('Hello Wolrd'));
```

but this doesn't work.

I'd want to say something like:

```
App::getLocalizedString('Hello World', 'es');
```

Also, I'll want to use it inside my Observer too, so I don't want to change user's locale. I just want to get a string based on given locale.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a locale as a third argument of `__` helper, e.g.:

`dd(__('Hello Wolrd', [], 'es'));`

Second argument is just a list of [parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization#retrieving-translation-strings), which in your specific example is empty.

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L938).